# Timeouts from Hikari pool

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, hikaricp

Getting frequent timeout failures on HikariCP. Though the connectionTimeout is set to 30 seconds, the requests are timing out before waiting for that duration.

Jdk: 18

DB: Postgresql  (42.3.5)

Hikaricp: 4.0.3

Spring boot: v2.7.0

**Logs:**

[image]

**Note:**

20:55:46 - there were 0 waiting connections

20:55:47 - 10 connections were active with another 10 waiting

20:55:53 - 10 active, 20 waiting

20:55:53 - Throws Connection is not available, request timed out error.

It's not a connection leak issue, as the active connection are not frozen.

**Hikari Configuration**:

Spring data jpa + Hibernate + jdbc

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://....
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
```

**HikariConfig Metrics:**

HikariConfig | HikariPool-1 - configuration:
HikariConfig | allowPoolSuspension................................false
HikariConfig | autoCommit................................true
HikariConfig | catalog................................none
HikariConfig | connectionInitSql................................none
HikariConfig | connectionTestQuery................................none
HikariConfig | connectionTimeout................................30000
HikariConfig | dataSource................................none
HikariConfig | dataSourceClassName................................none
HikariConfig | dataSourceJNDI................................none
HikariConfig | dataSourceProperties................................
HikariConfig | driverClassName................................"org.postgresql.Driver"
HikariConfig | exceptionOverrideClassName................................none
HikariConfig | healthCheckProperties................................{}
HikariConfig | healthCheckRegistry................................none
HikariConfig | idleTimeout................................600000
HikariConfig | initializationFailTimeout................................1
HikariConfig | isolateInternalQueries................................false
HikariConfig | keepaliveTime................................0
HikariConfig | leakDetectionThreshold................................30000
HikariConfig | maxLifetime................................1800000
HikariConfig | maximumPoolSize................................10
HikariConfig | metricRegistry................................none
HikariConfig | minimumIdle................................10
HikariConfig | password................................
HikariConfig | poolName................................"HikariPool-1"
HikariConfig | readOnly................................false
HikariConfig | registerMbeans................................false
HikariConfig | scheduledExecutor................................none
HikariConfig | schema................................none
HikariConfig | threadFactory................................internal
HikariConfig | transactionIsolation................................default
HikariConfig | username................................"postgres"
HikariConfig | validationTimeout................................5000

Comment: Can you also share the configuration of hikari that you have as update of the question ?

Comment: @AndreiLisa I have updated the question with configuration details. Let me know if you need any other information.